# How do you deal with edits that strip personal details of the author from a question, ultimately graveyarding the question?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question

I [posted on Super User about a rather particular issue about Windows 10 behaving *very* awkwardly to the point where I'd call the issue a bug](https://superuser.com/questions/1414055/shares-in-windows-keep-returning-after-being-disabled), since traditional methods of how you would normally fix this problem do nothing in my case.

Since I wrote the original question very badly, contextually and structurally of course everybody assumed I am not very sophisticated with technology or put zero to no effort into researching the problem, hence downvoting the question and upvoting comments with the intent of me bettering my question.

I tried to cater additional information to all comments as fast as possible and did a complete overhaul on the post.

Which I all understand. Questions on Stack Exchange should be compact, not beating around the bush, informative and educational. I love Stack Exchange's policy and therefore the site for this behaviour, because it results in a lot of quality content.

Where this kind of bit me in the ass though was when I was trying to damage-control the question by providing more context about *me and my knowledge* so that I could explain to the already few users that kept an eye on the thread would understand where I was coming from, explaining that I am actually pretty in-touch with a lot of things being a software developer and all that jazz.

Since this does not add any value to the question when breaking the post down into the crucial essentials, a moderator removed that section from my post.

**Which, I can't really say anything against, since it's very conform with SE's policies, but in return ultimately absolutely graveyarded my question with -4 votes and sub 50 views.**

So, this puts me in a dead lock. I seriously do not know how to approach this situation since the post is 100% dead, but also written as best as possible.

Comment: Your characterization of what happened seems to be, overall, wrong. [Your question](https://superuser.com/questions/1414055/shares-in-windows-keep-returning-after-being-disabled) wasn't "graveyarded" because personal information was stripped out. It was downvoted because it's a long, rambling mess of a question. It is very much not "written as best as possible".

Comment: **Your question has not been sent to the "graveyard", the question until recently, simply could not be answered.**  You should stop worrying about other examples, if it wasn't a moderator that attempted to clarify your question, it would have been somebody else.  The personal details were not necessary to answer the question.  The removal of unnecessary information is part of an editor's responsibility.

Comment: @beggarboy - You should simply take the steps to merge your different accounts.

Comment: Your question is just too long and complex.  Nobody is going to sift through all of that on a Q&A site.  If you really need to include that much detail to explain the question, it isn't a good fit for this type of site.  The site is designed around bite-sized questions for which the answers will be of value to others.  Yours won't help anyone else.  You also spend the first few paragraphs describing context that leaves the impression that the problem was created by doing "non-standard" things to tweak your system.  Most people's reaction to that is you're kind of on your own when you do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Since I wrote the original question very badly, contextually and structurally, of course, everybody assumed I am not very sophisticated with technology or put zero to no effort into researching the problem, hence downvoting the question and upvoting comments with the intent of me bettering my question.

The community voted on the quality of the contribution that you submitted.  It is good that you recognized a quality problem, but you really should have addressed that issue, before you submitted the question.

> I tried to cater additional information to all comments as fast as possible and did a complete overhaul on the post.

There is a ton of information in your question that should be simplified.

> Which, I can't really say anything against, since it's very conform with SE's policies, but in return ultimately absolutely graveyarded my question with -4 votes and sub 50 views.

You are never guaranteed an answer on a Stack Exchange community. As you point out, your issue is extremely specific, and until recently you even admit the quality of your question was low.  **However, your question, has not been sent to the graveyard.**

> So, this puts me in a dead lock. I seriously do not know how to approach this situation since the post is 100% dead, but also written as best as possible.

You should make any additional improvements you feel that might be required for an answer to be submitted.

Answer (score 2):

> … I was trying to … explain … where I was coming from,
>   explaining that I am actually pretty in-touch with a lot of things …

> > “I am very mature.” “I am very beautiful.” “I am very honest.” “I am very intelligent.”
> >     “I am actually pretty in-touch with a lot of things …”

You should probably never make statements like these (about yourself),
because people don’t care about your opinion. 
If you want people to believe that you are knowledgeable,
the way to do it is to demonstrate it in your question.

> … this does not add any value to the question …

I agree. 
You even said in the question “you can skip this”. 
So I don’t understand why you believe
that the removal of your rant harmed your question.

---

I agree with all the people who say that the question is hard to understand.

- > When I turn on my PC, Windows always resets two Shared Folders …

  I don’t know what you mean by “reset”.
- > In this case my harddrive roots of `A:\` & `D:\`.

  Again, I don’t know what you mean. 
  If these are remote shares,
  it’s confusing to refer to them as “hard drives”. 
  And, since you *show* a drive `B:`,
  you should probably (*briefly*) mention it.
- > Every drive letter you see … represents
  >   an actual singular physical harddrive on the back end.

  OK, maybe I’m just stupid, but I find “back end” unclear.

---

And while it’s great that you posted all those screenshots,
it seems to me that they’re a bit cluttered. 
You might want to crop your images to make them easier to read. 
I’ve done that for you (for three of the images).

Answer (score -1):

Others are posting specifics, but I want to focus on [this part of your question](https://superuser.com/revisions/1414055/6)—that was not a question at all—but just as follows:

> **Regarding the original post** (you can skip this)
>
> I would like to state that I have a fair amount of expertise when it comes to IT stuff, since I build pc's for fun, did and do a lot of troubleshooting for other users in need and much more in addition to my full time job as programmer.
>
> I feel I had to clarify my position and knowledge here, since the original post came across to many as a badly researched and lazy. Which really isn't my style, if you care to take a look at my other questions. I wrote this question originally pretty slacked off and tired, but also very pissed. I have to apologize for that, since I myself support SO's policy of keeping questions and answers high quality.
>
> I do not have a lot of rep on StackOverflow, but I have been here for quite a while, I just lurked a lot, since I actually use the search heavily before asking a question. Often resulting in me not needing to ask a question in the first place. So when I ask things in a more conversational and non-techy manner it's because I do not see the benefit of making or explaining things more complicated than they have to be. Please do not take this the wrong way. I ask the people who downvoted the question to reconsider their vote if the post now has an acceptable form in their eyes. I genuinely need help with this and being pushed down the algo doesn't exactly help me. I am aware that parts of the original post were lacking information, but if I am not even given time to cater to the comments while being notoriously downvoted to -3 honestly makes me angry.

Okay, you ready for this? Here it goes:

### If you are going to post a rambling 3 paragraph screed that begins with the parenthetical “you can skip this” and then end it with the words, “…honestly makes me angry.” You are only exacerbating your problem.

The reality is even the most complex issues can be simply explained. The problem with your question is your “personal details” are three paragraphs of a demanding, needy rants that are added on the pile of text that consists off your question which—in and of itself—is very unfocused.

The Stack Exchange community is not elitist. All that is really requested is clarity and focus.

My advice? Delete your original question, take a rest and then—when you are ready—repost the question with more clarity and focus. And don’t apologize or even reference the downvoted question.

FWIW, despite my level of rep I still post questions and answers that get downvoted. It’s part of the way things work sometimes. Some questions and answers I know are valid enough I will leave them up there. And guess what? I get upvotes on those *over time* and then it all evens out. The really bad posts? I just delete them.

Stack Exchange is not a clique or club. We are all here to support each other and share knowledge. Simple as that.